# Drag'N'Drop Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, события, drag-n-drop

В проекте использую http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid. Есть несколько дивов, между которыми можно перетягивать внутренние дивы. Задача состоит в том, что-бы узнать : 1. Внешний див, с  которого убрали внутренний див. 2. Внутренний див. 3. Другой внешний див, куда внутренний див положили. Есть ли какой-то ивент, что-бы можно было поймать эти дивы, т.к. в них находится нужная мне информация.
П.С. Прошу прощение за сумбурность.

Comment: А почему бы не воспользоваться http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists ? Скорее всего там будет нужная инфа при перетягивании. А уж блоки-квадратики как нибудь через `css` сделайте

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, хм, ничего подобного в описании не увидел. Хотя в любом случае спасибо за ответ.

Comment: почитайте еще тут, тут про события и как вообще работает драг и дроп http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось под рукой:
В метод `sortable()` дописал метод `stop: function (e, ui){}` , в котором при помощи `ui` и `this` поулчил необходимы данные. Т.к. этот метод есть `event handler`, то тут же отслеживалось это событие, что оказалось очень кстати.